# Event tracking with Adobe Launch

Tags: event-tracking, web-analytics, adobe-launch

I am trying to create a single event tracking (form submission) in Adobe Experience Platform data collection. I need to be able to see in Google Analytics the number of users who clicked on the submit button. I am a Data analyst and never used Adobe launch before. I assume this task is for someone with web analytics experience? It will be helpful to know.

Anyhow, on the browser's developer tools, I tried running the below command in the console

```
adobeDataLayer.getState();
```

However, I am getting the below error:

VM196:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: adobeDataLayer is not defined
at :1:1

Can someone please explain what is the issue? Do I need to define the adobe Data Layer. If yes, is that something I can do by referring to online resources or it's something that an experienced person can do considering I have a time limit to accomplish this task.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the Adobe Client Data Layer extension installed in Launch.
2. Make sure you're not blocking Launch, so like, no adblockers.

That's it. The adobeDataLayer.getState() should be available along with the data layer array itself.